# Binding Visibility to Viewmodel's property [ from View To ViewModel] from CodeBehind

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm creating binding dynamically on a DockManager in order to have in the ViewModel a property that tells me if the View/ViewModel are visible.

I've done some tests as I've done with other bindings but in this particular case I need to bind from the view to ViewModel and not the opposite

my code looks like

```
VisibilityToBooleanConverter converter = new VisibilityToBooleanConverter();
        
var myBinding = new Binding
{
    Source = pane.Content, //this is the view
    Path = new PropertyPath("Visibility"),
    Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
    UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged,
    Converter = converter
};

BindingOperations.SetBinding(pane.DataContext,) //<-- how do I tell that I've to bind to a ViewModel?

//BindingOperations.SetBinding((UIElement)pane.Content, UIElement.VisibilityProperty, myBinding); //this was the test I've done but with no luck
```

Any suggestion?

## UPDATE #1

I try to explain better my scenario, as I've been suggested.

I have a DockManager that shows different Views. Some of those views have real-time updated that's done really at high frequency. It's useless that they're updated if they are not visible.

So first I've tried to bind on IsVisible but it's not possible as you've told (no setter).

My question is it's possible to bind on the Visibility Property in code behind so that I can have this information somehow saved in the viewmodel

Comment: How does the view become visible? It seems to me that controlling that from the viewmodel would obviate your issue. Also. Is it really visibility you're interested or isvisible? Controls can be visibility visible but scrolled out a view eg.

Comment: The best would be to bind on IsVisible but as I've tried, it's not possible to bind to that field. The IsVisible is managed by the DockManager

Comment: Although isvisible is a dependency property, whoever invented it made it read only ( only has a getter). That means you can't bind it. Which means a behavior for those of use who do MVVM. I think more explanation of intent is advisable. I think you maybe asked kind of the wrong question. People will answer a question. That doesn't always really help as much as you might hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding needs a DependencyProperty. I would try to use Binding in `OneWayToSource` mode and bind `Visibility` property, using common BooleanToVisibilityConverter converter

```
var converter = new BooleanToVisibilityConverter();

var myBinding = new Binding
{
    Path = new PropertyPath("IsVisiblePropertyInViewModel"),
    Mode = BindingMode.OneWayToSource,
    UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged,
    Converter = converter
};

BindingOperations.SetBinding(pane, UIElement.VisibilityProperty, binding);
```

Comment: +1 but a the last line does not compile. The second parameter in the `SetBinding()` call should be `UIElement.VisibilityProperty`.